# How to add maxpooling layer for 2D data

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to use maxpooling layer after GlobalAveragePooling2D, I tried "MaxPooling2D layer
" and "GlobalMaxPooling2D layer", but these two layer only accept 4D tensor.

Is there a better way to do this?

Or should I need to create custom layer and excute maxpooling(x_temp)

```
x_temp = conv_base2(input_temp)
x_temp = tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x_temp)  
#x_temp = layers.maxpooling(x_temp)
```

```
conv_base2 (Functional)         (None, 8, 8, 1536)
global_average_pooling2d_2      (None, 1536)
#maxpooling                     (None, 768)
```

Comment: There is no way to do that, what you are trying to do makes no conceptual sense. MaxPooling expects a matrix, and global average pooling produces a vector.

Comment: Thank you , I think I should do this before global average pooling